# How to copy directory via scp within gradle task?

Tags: java, groovy, gradle, scp

What is a clean and elegant way to copy a bunch of files via scp with Gradle?

Two ways I currently see are:

- Using Apache Wagon, as described here: http://markmail.org/message/2tmtaffayhq25g4s
- Executing scp via command line with the Exec task

Are there any better (more obvious) ways to approach this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From a project of mine that I use to SCP files to an EC2 server.
The jar files there are local files that are part of my project, I forget where I got them from.  There's probably a more concise way of doing all this, but I like to be very explicit in my build scripts.

```
configurations {
  sshAntTask
}

dependencies {
  sshAntTask fileTree(dir:'buildSrc/lib', include:'jsch*.jar')
  sshAntTask fileTree(dir:'buildSrc/lib', include:'ant-jsch*.jar')
}

ant.taskdef(
  name: 'scp',
  classname: 'org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.ssh.Scp',
  classpath: configurations.sshAntTask.asPath)

task uploadDbServer() {
  doLast  {
    ant.scp(
      file: '...',
      todir: '...',
      keyfile: '...' )
  }
}
```

Comment: Many Thanks @Shorn for this clean and explicit way (and put it into an own configuration), which I do also anticipate in advantage to allow easier maintenance.

Comment: Both of those artifacts are available from Maven central.  It makes the config very easy.

Comment: I'm noticing that Gradle comes with jsch... so isn't there a better, more Gradle way, to do this?

Comment: your dependencies could read like this, from maven:

`sshAntTask 'org.apache.ant:ant-jsch:1.7.1', 'jsch:jsch:0.1.29'`

Comment: @djKianoosh yes maybe it's better to put that as the default answer.. for gradle noobs like me it adds yet another hurdle.

Comment: http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/12/gradle-goodness-using-optional-ant-task.html  describes much the same approach.  Another good example

Answer (score 31):

A few years after the original question, I like [the Gradle SSH Plugin](https://gradle-ssh-plugin.github.io/). A small quote of its extensive [documentation](https://gradle-ssh-plugin.github.io/docs/):

> We can describe SSH operations in the session closure.
>
> ```
> session(remotes.web01) {
>   // Execute a command
>   def result = execute 'uptime'
>
>   // Any Gradle methods or properties are available in a session closure
>   copy {
>     from "src/main/resources/example"
>     into "$buildDir/tmp"
>   }
>
>   // Also Groovy methods or properties are available in a session closure
>   println result
> }
> ```
>
> Following methods are available in a session closure.
>
> - `execute` - Execute a command.
> - `executeBackground` - Execute a command in background.
> - `executeSudo` - Execute a command with sudo support.
> - `shell` - Execute a shell.
> - `put` - Put a file or directory into the remote host.
> - `get` - Get a file or directory from the remote host.

...and allows for, for example:

```
task deploy(dependsOn: war) << {
  ssh.run {
    session(remotes.staging) {
      put from: war.archivePath.path, into: '/webapps'
      execute 'sudo service tomcat restart'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this should be the answer, and have way more upvotes

Comment: @Bender Sure, but It was written almost 3 years after the question been asked.

Comment: Indeed, @Kamil Even more, my 7 years old answer may very well be outdated by now. (I've not used Gradle myself for many years now.)

Comment: @Arjan sure but the plugin still works fine and is easy to implement into a build + i have yet to find smth similar on the gradle site/community forum and was exactly what i was looking for