# Gradle > How to deploy a JAR with only its needed dependencies jars to a remote computer

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I am a new Gradle user. My task is to build a Gradle based project and then copy the final jar along with its dependencies jars to a remote host.

My approach is to do a local build, and then copy dependencies jars from caches to a local directory with a gradle task, which looks like:

```
task copyDependencies(type: Copy) {
  from configurations.runtime
  into "build/libs/deps"
}
```

But this task copies all the dependencies, say including **transitive dependencies** to the target directory; moreover, the runtime group include  compile dependencies by default. So I would like to exclude the transitive dependencies, which takes great amount of space and the compile time dependencies jars. Is there any solution?

At last I plan to copy the generated jar and dependencies jars to a remote host by means of ssh, but I guess there should a way to directly finish this by means of a gradle task

Faithfully hope someone can give some useful hint

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a fatJar, you can find an example on how to do it here:

[Building a uberjar with Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10986244/building-a-uberjar-with-gradle)

For copying to a remote directory you can get an example using an ant task here :[How to copy directory via scp within gradle task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13183433/how-to-copy-directory-via-scp-within-gradle-task)

Or alternatively you can use an Exec task which will an external tool (scp for example) : https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html

Hope this helps